# Visual Studio OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small problem on OpenFileDialog. I have a menubar where people will choose an exact file. But the problem is, when I change values and save it, it's not changing on OpenFileDialog1. Also I want to give a message if the person chooses a wrong file, for example, he/she has to choose *.exe but chooses something else, then a message has to pop up and say wrong file.
Here is my code:

```cs
private void chooseGamesFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Game's Exe File";
                    
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
    
        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Exe files (*.exe)";//"txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    
        openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
        openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;
    };
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file has been selected successfully!", "Norges Online", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
    else
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel ?
            MessageBox.Show("The file has been selected wrong!", "Norges Online", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
    
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: You got the tags of the question wrong. `OpenFileDialog` is not related to Visual Studio, it is just one component of Winforms. Also, the language your code is in is `c#`, not `c++` or `vb.net`.

Comment: Is there some reason this repeats? `openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;`

Comment: Your object naming does not allow others understand what you are trying to do. So far I have counted 3 different `OpenFileDialog` objects: 1- `this.openFileDialog1`. 2- `openFileDialog1` created inside the `chooseGamesFileToolStripMenuItem_Click` event and 3- `openFileDialog1` created inside the `openFileDialog1_FileOk` event.

Comment: Its really not clear what you are trying to achieve here and the code you've supplied isn't making it much clearer I'm afraid. When you say you 'change values and save it' what exactly do you mean? Why in the handler for the Ok button being clicked (I assumed from the naming) do you create a new dialog and open it?? I have more questions but I'm running out of space

Comment: Do notice that calling `.ShowDialog()` forces the popup to show so the user chooses a file. That is why you should only call it once if you want to do an if-else check (to avoid an extra popup in the else statement). You could `DialogResult chosenOption = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` and later `if (chosenOption == DialogResult.OK)`... `else if (chosenOption == DialogResult.Cancel)`. You could also use a `switch` statement if you like.

Comment: Do users have access right to file? Or you closing file after reading so the file can be opened in write mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void chooseGamesFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            {
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Game's Exe File";

                openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
                openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                
                openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Exe File (sro_client.exe)|sro_client.exe";//"txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
                openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

                openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
                openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;
            };
            
            DialogResult chosenOption = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (chosenOption == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file has been selected successfully!", "Norges Online", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            else if (chosenOption == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file didn't select yet!", "Norges Online", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this);

            }

        }
```